# Flexbox collapse text in safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, mobile-safari

Faced with simple bug in safari, guess I'm not first, but not found any similar question.

Simple case: header where a button with text and some long title

```css
.one {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.back {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #f00;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <span class="back">Back</span>
    <p class="text">asd asda sda sd asd asda sda sdasd asda sda sdasd asda sda sdasd asda sda sdasd asda sda sdasd asda sda sdasd asda sda sdasd asda sda sdasd asda sda sdasd asda sda sdasd asda sda sd</p>
  </div>
```

it's works fine in chromium browsers and ff, but broken in safari(button collapsed)
for now I solve it just remove text and show only static size icon for mobiles, but what correct solution if I wanna use it with text.

set `min-width: 0` for `.text` not helps; set min/max width for button I too can't do, cause I don't know how long will be text(in different section and languages)